# Arabic Text Stroke Overlap

Tags: adobe-illustrator, stroke, fill, arabic

hope you're doing well. I'm having issues with the arabic text stroke overlapping between the Arabic characters. I know how to prevent this with zero fill and white fill, but I want to add a patterned photo with the text. Here's how far I can get while the text won't look like it's overlapping.

[image]

After this point, I try to make a clipping mask, but I end with this:

[image]

The individual letters end up overlapping whenever I try to make a clipping mask. How do I remove the stroke overlap between the individual Arabic characters while also having a picture pattern as the fill?

Comment: Don't you mean Persian? :)

Comment: Search on here for how to use Illustrator's Shape Builder tool.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly moving the stroke *below* the fill in the Appearance Panel will correct the issue.... or combine the text into *one* shape, or compound shape, as opposed to a collection of shapes.